# Как решить проблему с IndexOutOfBounds?

Tags: java, матрицы

Всем доброго времени суток. Я начинающий программист на Java, делаю программу похожую на калькулятор массивов. Проблема заключается в Ошибке:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at Main.input_matrix(Main.java:43)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Я знаю что она значит, проблема в том что я не могу понять из-за чего она возникает(Метод: input_matrix())
Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int[][][] matrix_1 = new int[1][3][3];
    public static int[][] AnswerArray = new int[3][2];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        input_matrix();
        System.out.println("Multiply matrix");
        draw_3Array();
        Logic();
        draw_Answer_Array();
        System.out.println("--------------");
        sort_in_row();
        sort_in_column();
        replace_elements_rows_and_columns();
        System.out.println("Answer after sort");
        System.out.println("--------------");
        draw_Answer_Array();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
    }


    public static int[] input_matrix() {
        Scanner count_of_rows = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner count_of_columns = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner count_of_elements_in_row = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = count_of_rows.nextInt();
        int j = count_of_columns.nextInt();
        int k = count_of_elements_in_row.nextInt();
        int[][][] matrix_1 = new int[i][j][k];
        System.out.println(matrix_1[i][j][k]);
        return null;
    }

    public static void draw_3Array() {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix_1[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < matrix_1[i][j].length; k++) {
                    if (j == 0 && k == 0 || j == 1 && k == 0 || j == 2 && k == 0) {
                        System.out.print("|");
                    }

                    System.out.print(matrix_1[i][j][k] + " ");
                    if (k == 2 || i == 1 && k == 1) {
                        System.out.println("|");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void draw_Answer_Array() {

        for (int i = 0; i < AnswerArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < AnswerArray[i].length; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0 || i == 1 && j == 0 || i == 2 && j == 0) {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }

                System.out.print(AnswerArray[i][j] + " ");
                if (i == 0 && j == 1 || i == 1 && j == 1 || i == 2 && j == 1) {
                    System.out.println("|");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Logic() {
        //Перемножение
        System.out.println("Answer");

    }

    public static void sort_in_row() {
        //Sort by choosing
        boolean isSorted_row = false;
        int buf;
        while (!isSorted_row) {
            isSorted_row = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < AnswerArray.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < AnswerArray[i].length - 1; j++) {
                    if (AnswerArray[i][j] >= AnswerArray[i][j + 1]) {
                        isSorted_row = false;
                        buf = AnswerArray[i][j];
                        AnswerArray[i][j] = AnswerArray[i][j + 1];
                        AnswerArray[i][j + 1] = buf;
                        //System.out.println("|" + AnswerArray[i][j] + "|" + AnswerArray[i][j+1] + "|");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void sort_in_column() {
        boolean isSorted_column = false;
        int buf;
        while (!isSorted_column) {
            isSorted_column = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < AnswerArray.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < AnswerArray[i].length; j++) {
                    if (AnswerArray[i][j] > AnswerArray[i + 1][j]) {
                        isSorted_column = false;
                        buf = AnswerArray[i][j];
                        AnswerArray[i][j] = AnswerArray[i + 1][j];
                        AnswerArray[i + 1][j] = buf;
                        //System.out.println("|" + AnswerArray[i][j] + "|" + AnswerArray[i][j+1] + "|");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void replace_elements_rows_and_columns() {
        int help_variable_1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < AnswerArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < AnswerArray[i].length - 1; j++) {
                if (AnswerArray[i][j + 1] > AnswerArray[i + 1][j]) {
                    help_variable_1 = AnswerArray[i + 1][j];
                    AnswerArray[i + 1][j] = AnswerArray[i][j + 1];
                    AnswerArray[i][j + 1] = help_variable_1;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.
Всем хорошего дня.

Comment: "я не могу понять из-за чего она возникает" --- Возьмите отладку пройдитесь построчно по своему коду и узнаете. Тем более примерные строчки кода вы уже знаете из сообщения об ошибке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(matrix_1[i][j][k]);
```

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему элементу массива.

Так как переменная i в вашем коде это кол-во элементов в массиве, то последний элемент будет иметь индекс i-1, а не i, потому что нумерация элементов массива начинается с [нуля](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.4.php). Аналогично для j и k.

В вашем случае для вывода последнего элемента массива стоит использовать код ниже.

```
System.out.println(matrix_1[i-1][j-1][k-1]);
```

Если же вы хотите вывести всю матрицу, воспользуйтесь своим же методом *draw_3Array()*